# sipp pcap play packets sent from port '0' if i literally mention media port in scenario file

Tags: sipp

I am using sipp pcap play to send media from one particular port after sending 183 Session In Progress response. I can achieve this using -mp parameter. But After sending 200 OK, I want to send media from different media port, which I can't as if I mention media port in scenario file, sipp sends media packets from port '0'.

How to solve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**In Media Description parameter**,

183 Session Progress, you can give like this in sipp file.

```
m=audio [media_port+2]  RTP/AVP 18
```

For instance, your running a sipp file with **-mp 7896** media port, sipp file run play pcap file with **7898 port**.

200 OK, Similarly

```
m=audio [media_port+4]  RTP/AVP 18
```

Here also, sipp file play a pcap file with **7900 port**.